# Is there any shortcut for traditional arrow keys in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide, arrow-keys

I am new to PyCharm IDE by JetBrains and every time I have to leave the home row and click on those arrows for navigation. Is there any shortcut keys such as Ctrl, Shift something or if there isn't Can I create my own shortcut.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "home row"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure custom shortcuts in **Settings | Keymap | Editor Actions** if I correctly understand your usecase:

[image]